# Appharbor: "If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully...."

Tags: nginx, cloud, appharbor

I deployed my application to appharbor, after it show message when i clicked on
**(Go to Application)**

"Welcome to nginx!
    If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

until I realized I needed to clear my browser cache or open the page in a new browser, or clear the cache. Its works for me.